# Order in matrix products, Complex conjugation, Transpose, dagger, ...

Tags: matrices

First, state what i know about products of matrices 
\begin{align}
& (AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1} \\
&(AB)^T = B^T A^T \\
& (AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger} A^{\dagger}
\end{align}
Where $-1$ represents the inverse, $T$ transpose $\dagger$ dagger (which means the complex conjugate and transpose)

Now, I got wonder the complex conjugation of matrices 
It seems to me that complex conjugation itself does not change the order of products,

\begin{align}
(AB)^{*} = A^* B^*
\end{align}
Is this statement correct?

Comment: Yes, youare right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Generalizations

Comment: @John Hughes, Yes i have tried. $i.e$, $\begin{pmatrix}i & 0 \\ 0 &i \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}-i & 0 \\ 0 &i \end{pmatrix}$. I see the above relation holds

Comment: @Emillio Novati, Thanks! I just confused with some basic stuff, Maybe i have to be more careful reading technical stuffs!

Comment: If the relation holds for $A$ and $B$ both having $1$s or $i$s in each place, then it holds for all $A$ and $B$, by a linearity argument. :)